# how would you prove that polynomial functions are not exponential?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, exponential-function, solution-verification

here is one proof that I know but I am not totally sure if it is acceptable-

exponential functions are exponential: no matter how many times you differentiate them 
e.g-

**f(x)=e^x**
*first derivative f`(x)= e^x

2nd derivative f``(x)= e^x

3rd derivative f```(x)=e^x*
        and so on.

now if you differentiate a polynomial function-
let's say,

**f(x)= x^5**
*1st derivative f`(x)= 5x^4

2nd de3rivative f``(x)= 20x^3

3rd derivatives f```(x)=60x^2

4th derivative f````(x)=120x

5th derivative f`````(x)= 0*
like this every polynomial finally gets differentiated to zero or a constant . this proves that the polynomials are not exponential.

```
                        **is my proof ok**
```

I want more alternate proofs and a brief explanation about this one.

Comment: Your proof is fine if we just want to prove that $p(x)$ is not $e^x$. But how do we know that $p(x)=e^{f(x)}$ has no solution whatever function $f$ is? For example, if $p(x)=x^2+1$, $e^{\ln(p(x))}=p(x)$ which is a polynomial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You can also say that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x=0$, whereas you have$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}P(x)=\pm\infty$$if $P$ is a non-constant polynomial function. And, clearly, the exponential function is not constant.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $e^x=P(x)$, where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Note first that $n\gt0$, since $e^x$ is nonconstant.  It follows that $P(2x)$ and $(P(x))^2$ are polynomials of *different* degrees, namely $n$ and $2n$. But $P(2x)=e^{2x}=(e^x)^2=(P(x))^2$ says they are of the same degree, which is a contradiction. So $e^x$ is not equal to any polynomial.